# Cannot see visualforce page in the content source drop down

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I have created a visualforce page but can't see it in the content source drop down when creating New list Button  for a custom object  . Please help!.

Comment: To be used to override standard actions, Visualforce pages must follow the convention of extending a standard controller. See section 3 of e.g. [Overriding Buttons, Links, and Tabs with Visualforce](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_customize_override.htm).

Comment: @KeithC:Thanks for your reply.Based on the doc i have created a vf page